# Select IQueryable rows where datatime is null in the database

Tags: c#, datetime, null, iqueryable

I have an IQueryable that is supplied data from a SQL connection. There is a DateTime column in this which can contain nulls. I basically need to be able to get all the rows that have a null datetime value but nothing I am trying seems to work. 
This is something like my latest attempt but it just simply fails trying to convert the "null" string to a DateTime format:

```
IQueryable dataByDate = allData.Where("DateTimeColumnName" + " == @0", (dateValueVariableAsString == null) ? "NULL" : dateValueVariableAsString );
```

If dateValueVariableAsString has a string with of a valid DateTime format then the I do get the results I expect - however I just cant seem to be able to get the rows where the dateColumn has nulls.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got this sorted with the following alteration to my example above:

```
IQueryable dataByDate = allData.Where("DateTimeColumnName == null", null);
```